# Como impedir a tela de rotacionar?

Tags: objective-c, mobile, xcode

Estou fazendo um APP e gostaria que a tela ficasse sempre em Portrait.
Pesquisei na internet sobre, mas não consegui descobrir.
tentei usar o UIInterfaceOrientation do framework UIKit, mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil de se fazer, é através das configurações do projeto.

Selecione o seu projeto principal(no caso de exemplo é PMB), e após isso escolha o *target* que você irá realizar essa alteração (provavelmente só terá 1 opção para você selecionar, a não ser que você tenha criado vários targets).

Vá na aba **General** > **Deployment info** e deixe somente a orientação que você quer, nesse caso, *portrait*.

[image: selecione seu projeto]
[image: selecione o target]
[image: selecionar somente portrait]

Answer (score -1):

Consegui achar uma forma :D

Usando UIKit.framework

Arquivo.h

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

Arquivo.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.supportedInterfaceOrientations;  
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```